# Difference between set_ and mutable_ methods in protobuf file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have below sample protobuf file, which contains following methods
could you please help me to understand when to use `set_name()` and when to use `mutable_name()`.
As per my understanding both methods sets value to name field.

```
  inline void set_name(const char* value);
  inline ::std::string* mutable_name();
```

Comment: `mutable_name` doesnt set anything. It returns a pointer

Comment: Of the two `set_name` is the more obvious, but if for any reason you needed to get a pointer to the name so that you can modify the name later then use `mutable_name`.

Comment: *"As per my understanding both methods sets value to name field."* -- how do you see `mutable_name` setting a value? Suppose you want to set the name to "Super". You call `mutable_name()` -- how does this call know that you intend the name to be "Super" instead of "Sumo"?

Answer (score 2):

`std::string* mutable_name()` does not set something. Perhaps you refer to a call like `*mutable_name() = "blabla";`. If this was the only usage then it would do the same as `set_name`, but it is not the only usage. `mutable_name` returns a pointer that can be stored and used later to set the name.

For illustration I will use a toy model:

```
#include <string>

struct named_thing {
     std::string name;
     void set(const std::string n) { name = n; }
     std::string* get_mutable() { return &name; }
};
```

The `set` method you can use to set the name. I suppose its clear how to use it. The `get_mutable` on the other hand can be used to set the string at some later point. You could write a custom class that stores the pointer:

```
 struct name_setter {
     std::string* name = nullptr;
     void set(const std::string& n) { *name = n; }
     void rebind(std::string* n) { name = n; }
 };
```

`name_setter` does not need the whole `named_thing`, it only needs a `std::string*` to set it.

```
int main() {
   named_thing foo{ "foo" };
   name_setter bar{ &foo.name };
   bar.set("bar");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to modify a member variable that is a struct, using `set_xxx()` requires you to construct a struct instance beforehand and pass it in. On the other hand, if you use `mutable_xxx()`, you can simply call `mutable_xxx()` to obtain a raw pointer and modify it, **which is particularly useful when you need to modify a specific part of the variable.** For example, you can use the syntax `mutable_xxx()->mutable_xxx_part()->mutable_xxx_field() = xxx` to modify a specific field within the struct. The use of `mutable_xxx` has lower overhead compared to `set_xxx` in this situation.